# Would repeatedly importing and exporting H.246 video result in loss of quality?

Tags: video, premiere, quality

After exporting a time lapse video as H.246 mp4 using Adobe Premiere I realized I wanted a second copy without sound, but I had already changed the settings.  To save time I simply imported the mp4 to Premiere and then exported it again with the same H.246 settings but without the audio channel.

After close analysis of the 2 files I can't perceive any loss in quality, but I worry that I may have lost a tiny bit of quality through this process. Would repeating this process eventually result in noticeable loss of quality?

Answer (score 2):

Compression by default is removing information. “Lossless” compression, if repeated, will indeed result in degradation after a few generations.

Higher compression rates will degrade after fewer generations.

Answer (score 1):

If you give same bitrate setting (I assume it is configurable in Adobe Premiere), I don't expect you perceive the quality difference.

You could use FFMPEG to remove the audio on your first output with `-an` flag. Command will be like

`ffmpeg -i first_output.mp4-c copy -an nosound_output.mp4`

[Reference](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html#SEC8)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your FFMPEG solution to see if there was any difference.  Resulting total bit rates as follows:
1st output: 42953kbps
2nd output: 42584kbps
FFMPEG output: 42629kbps